# Aftermarket wheels - Dodge Grand Caravan

Tags: wheels, dodge, aftermarket-upgrade, replacements

I own a 2012 Dodge Grand Caravan SXT. My wheel has been damaged beyond repair. I am not in a position to buy the OEM wheel. I know there are aftermarket wheels available that will do the job. My mechanic is willing to fix the wheel once I have purchased it.

I have the following questions.

- How do I know if the wheel is 16 inch or 17 inch?
- Can I buy just 1    wheel or do I need to buy 4 since these are
  aftermarket?
- If I buy 1 wheel, what material should I select? I noticed wheels come in both steel as well aluminum.

**Edited:**

The tire spec says 235/60/R16 on the driver side passenger. So it is a 16 inch wheel, if I reading that right.

Comment: What are the dimensions shown on the tire? 195/60/16 or 195/60/17 etc...

Comment: That is a super-popular car.  You should be able to easily get a matching wheel at a junk yard or maybe even someone on craigslist that bought aftermarket wheels and is selling the OEMs.

Comment: You'll have no problem finding a used OEM, and be glad! I had an 83 AMC Concord and needed a new wheel, they were so rare a used one would have run me $60, which I didn't have. I ended up getting what they called the "wagon wheel", the only one that would fit, it looked ridiculous.

Comment: If you can't find a match at a junk yard, you can get one on the internet. I got one for about $ 100 - the dealer wanted $ 800 ( regular Nissan aluminum wheel. )

Comment: @JPhi1618 I followed your suggestion. I got the wheel at a local junkyard. It retailed for $100.00 over there.